# Deleting words while preserving clipboard

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, words, deletion

Is there a way to keep the clipboard contents when deleting entire words with `M-DEL`?

For instance, I'd like to delete a word (`M-DEL`) and then paste (`C-y`) what I had previously copied (with `ctrl+c`) from a different application. Is this possible?

Comment: In the event that the existing answers hereinbelow are insufficient to address the needs of the O.P., or a future forum reader via Google, there is a way to create a custom function that separates the Emacs clipboard from the system-wide clipboard.  I personally use `C-u` with my custom function when copying or pasting to add/retrieve items to/from the system clipboard ....  But, there is some defgeneric stuff that Stefan wrote a few years ago that complicates things depending upon the platform Emacs is running on, and I had to spend quite a bit of time setting up my own custom function ...

Comment: For future readers, this can be achieved easily by unsetting the variable: `(setq select-enable-clipboard nil)`. See the emacs manual (in section Emacs (top) > Killing > Cut and Paste > Clipboard). If you want, you can instead yank to and paste from the primary selection instead (esp. Linux users) by setting the variable `(setq select-enable-primary t)`. I'm not sure if this works cross-platform though. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196020/how-to-stop-emacs-from-contaminating-the-clipboard) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

No. `M-DEL` is bound to the function `backward-kill-word`, which calls `kill-region`. Anything that calls `kill-region` puts the killed text into the `kill-ring`, and also into the system clipboard. This is what differentiates the “kill commands” from commands that merely delete text from the buffer.

You could call `delete-region` instead, or you could paste from the clipboard before killing any text.

I recommend the latter, though you may also want to know about the `exchange-point-and-mark` command. Yanking text will set the mark just before inserting the yanked text, so you can yank something, run `exchange-point-and-mark` (bound to `C-x C-x` by default) to go back to where you started, then call `backward-kill-word`. This should do what you want.

There is no `backward-delete-word`, but it is trivial to write it yourself if you really want it:

```
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-word (- arg)))

(defun delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of Emacs, by default, `delete-backward-char` (`DEL`, i.e. <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>) [deletes the region if it is active](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Deletion.html). So you can delete instead of killing by selecting, then pressing `DEL`. If you want `C-d` or `delete` (<kbd>Del</kbd>) to do that, bind them to `delete-forward-char` instead of the default `delete-char`.

If you enable [`delete-selection-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Using-Region.html#index-delete_002dselection_002dmode), then most commands that insert something, including `yank`, delete the selection if it is active. This does what you want here, but may not be what you want in other circumstances.

Alternatively, call `rotate-yank-pointer` with the numeric argument 0 (i.e. `M-0 M-x r o - y RET` — you may need to type more characters depending on what other commands with a similar name are present in your Emacs instance). This saves the system clipboard in the [kill ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html). Then kill whatever you want (which clobbers the system clipboard), then access the [next-to-last kill ring entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Earlier-Kills.html) with `C-2 C-y` (`yank` with the numeric argument 2) or `C-y M-y` (`yank` then `yank-pop`).